# Android Bottom Navigation Activity gives a Null Pointer Exception in onCreate

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, bottomnavigationview, appbar

I added a Bottom Navigation Activity to my project but when i start the relevant activity it gives out a Null Pointer Exception.

It says that the exception is fired at line number 28

> at lk.apiit.eea.mobile.Activities.CompanyProfile.onCreate(CompanyProfile.java:28)

Following is the Exception and the Code
PLease help me fix this.. Thank you

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lk.apiit.eea.mobile/lk.apiit.eea.mobile.Activities.CompanyProfile}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2720)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1508)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at androidx.navigation.ui.ActionBarOnDestinationChangedListener.setTitle(ActionBarOnDestinationChangedListener.java:48)
    at androidx.navigation.ui.AbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener.onDestinationChanged(AbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener.java:100)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(NavController.java:218)
    at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(NavigationUI.java:220)
    at lk.apiit.eea.mobile.Activities.CompanyProfile.onCreate(CompanyProfile.java:28)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6720)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2673)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1508) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

An this is the code in onCreateMethod

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_company_profile);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
}
```

Comment: What theme are you using? Generally, you'd need a call to `setSupportActionBar()` in your Activity before you can call `setupActionBarWithNavController`

Comment: android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> this is what im using under <application>

Comment: So what is the parent of your `AppTheme`?

Comment: Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: changed it to DarkActionBar and it works.Thanks alot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you aren't calling `setSupportActionBar()` and you are using a `NoActionBar` theme, then you don't have an ActionBar. `setupActionBarWithNavController()` assumes you have an ActionBar, hence the NullPointerException.

You should switch to a theme that provides an ActionBar or call `setSupportActionBar()` with a `Toolbar` in your layout before calling `setupActionBarWithNavController()`.

Comment: Makes sense now.. i had  a the parent theme as NoActionBar. So i guess ill have to change theme for each activity if its not needed.

Comment: Generally, you'd [follow the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html#add-toolbar) and add a Toolbar as your action bar if you need an ActionBar

Answer (score 1):

Navigation graph is searching for the default app bar and in case if you don't have a default action bar in your code then please remove the line.

```
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
```