# Splash screen with (Architecture Navigation Components) and BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, kotlin, splash-screen, android-databinding, android-theme

I trying to implement splash screen to my app that contains `BottomNavigationView` with three fragments, and I used The best known method, like the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15832037/4205927) to do that without create new activity or fragment but the problem accrued after lunching splash screen directly, its getting **"RuntimeException and NullPointerException"**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mml.foody, PID: 6868
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mml.foody/com.mml.foody.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.navigation.ui.ActionBarOnDestinationChangedListener.setTitle(ActionBarOnDestinationChangedListener.java:48)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.AbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener.onDestinationChanged(AbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener.java:103)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(NavController.java:233)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(NavigationUI.java:237)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.ActivityKt.setupActionBarWithNavController(Activity.kt:74)
        at com.mml.foody.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6868 SIG: 9
```

**the style**

```
<style name="SplashScreenStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    </style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mml.foody">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/SplashScreenStyle"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.DetailsActivity"
            android:label="Details"
            android:theme="@style/DetailsActivityStyle">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ui.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/lightGray"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">


        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_container"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

MainActivity class

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding:ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var navHostFragment: NavHostFragment
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setTheme(R.style.SplashScreenStyle)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        setContentView(binding.root)


        navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_container) as NavHostFragment

        navController = navHostFragment.navController

        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(R.id.recipesFragment, R.id.favoriteRecipesFragment, R.id.foodJokeFragment)
        )

        binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)



    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp() ||  super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

[image]

After googling for this exception I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60214892/4205927) and I realised that this error because I using `NoActionBar` in the splash screen and also used this navigation component `setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)`
but I have old version of this app with the same structure and code and everything except one thing it's working with `plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` but I used databinding in main_activity.xml and its working fine, So what's the thing I missed it or how can fix this without creating new activity/fragmet ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightGray"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you want a splash screen with app that contains a action bars or bottom navigation view you you should create a separately activity or fragment, I prefer to doing that with fragment due to it's lightweight and best performance than activity

1. create a Splash Fragment like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_screen"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.SplashScreenFragment">
</FrameLayout>
```

2. in navGraph add action from SplashFragment to your Home frgament

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/splashScreenFragment"
        android:name="com.mml.foody.ui.fragments.SplashScreenFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_splash_screen">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_splashScreenFragment_to_yourHomeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/yourHomeFragment"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpTo="@id/splashScreenFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
```

with this three attributes will grantee that when click on back button the app go out and not back to the splash fragment

```
app:launchSingleTop="true"
app:popUpTo="@id/splashScreenFragment"
app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```

3. add this code to **SplashFragment class** to hide action bar only in fragment

```
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar?.hide()
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash_screen, container, false)


    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
            goToRecipesFragment()
        }

    }



    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar!!.show()
    }

    private suspend fun goToRecipesFragment() {
        delay(3000)
        findNavController()
            .navigate(SplashScreenFragmentDirections.actionSplashScreenFragmentToRecipesFragment())
    }
}
```

and finally to hide **`bottomNavigationView`** add this method to **MainActivity**

```
  navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            if(destination.id == R.id.splashScreenFragment) {

                binding.bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {

                binding.bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
```

Comment: Mr Mido -> this seems to be a better approach. Thank your MML

Answer (score 1):

The issue is occuring here: `setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)`. You are setting up an **ActionBar** that doesn't exists which leads to `NullPointerException`. Refer to the official doc for more info: [Navigation Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#setupActionBarWithNavController(androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity,androidx.navigation.NavController,androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration)), [Support Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity#getSupportActionBar())

Solutions: (choose one)
1/ **if** you don't need an ActionBar remove this line: 
 `setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)` in your MainActivity's `onCreate(...)` method

2/ **else** use an activity for the splash screen and create a style for the rest of the activities.

```
<style name="ActivitiesScreenStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
</style>
```

In your android manifest:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/ActivitiesScreenStyle"
    ...
    <activity android:name=".ui.YourSplashScreenActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashScreenStyle">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

This means your *fragment navigation* is happening on another activity than `YourSplashScreenActivity` otherwise you'll get the same error again.

Cheers mate !

Comment: this seems work but... after splashscreen the ugly action bar appear in the next screen instead the default one, I have old version of this app with the same structure and with `setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)` and it's worked fine, I am confused I don't know what's different, maybe some old libs

Comment: you have to create a custom toolbar/actionbar. Refer to this blog for how to create it: https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-create-custom-appbar-actionbar-toolbar-in-android-studio-java-61907fa1e44. Also, use a `.NoActionBar` theme for the app. Please, accept my answer because it solved your issue.

Comment: @a-david unfortunately this uncomplete solution for the issue,  I tried to create a custom action bar for the main fragment but I got the old error again, don't worry I do +1 for your try and thank you

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't fully help you, at least you know the source of the issue now. Thank you as well for the upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `android:theme="@style/SplashScreenStyle"` from `application` to

```
<activity android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashScreenStyle">
```

and setting `AppTheme` in `onCreateView`
because it looks like you are using

```
setTheme(R.style.SplashScreenStyle)
```

in your `MainActivity.kt`

[Refer my code](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Habbit/blob/eac5d25ae8aadb261052a6b69c3242ad227b645c/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L30)

Comment: I tried this and no changes, also I used this `setTheme(R.style.SplashScreenStyle)` in MainActivity not in fragment

Comment: What Iam trying to say is you are using `setTheme(R.style.SplashScreenStyle)` in MainActivity where you need to use a theme for your application like `setTheme(R.style.MyDefaultLightTheme)` and hence it is crashing because of lack of resources